# ob_start and include issue

Tags: php, output-buffering

Our website has been up for a couple of years and something has changed that's really strange. I've tried talking to the hosting but nothing gets resolved.

The issue is that the everything before the first`<?php` tag in the first included file gets output directly before going into the OB

For example:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<?php 
include('contentbox1.php'); 
include('contentbox2.php'); 
include('contentbox3.php'); 
?>
<b>Bye</b>
<?php
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo("Included{".$content."}");
?>
```

What gets output is this: (Notice that `<h1>Welcome</h1>` is not with the rest of the content that was output inside the buffer)

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
Included{
<div id="contentbox1"></div>
<div id="contentbox2"></div>
<div id="contentbox3"></div>
<b>Bye</b>
}
```

What the correct output should be (and is on my local machine):

```
Included{
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<div id="contentbox1"></div>
<div id="contentbox2"></div>
<div id="contentbox3"></div>
<b>Bye</b>
}
```

It's causing major issues to our site and I can't figure out why. It works perfectly on my local machine, just not the hosting that we've been with for years.

**SOLUTION:**
It turns out that while I was reuploading the `test.php`, the boxes of content and many other files on my website had gone funny and were possibly corrupted. Once I re-uploaded my entire site (even though no code changes had occured), my site which was running slowly is now super fast and all issues are gone. I've had my files corrupted with other hosts too so keep this in mind if you have weird stuff too in the future.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: what is the content of contentbox1.php ? is it only the html in your Q ?

Comment: what are the php versions on both servers, and on what platform?

Comment: is this the actual code or just a concept of the problem?

Comment: @Shehabix This is actual code.

Comment: The issue could be that ob_start doesn't really work, and ob is flushed after the <h1> if it's preceded by other output then the rest is caught by your ob_get_clean

Comment: @John Server PHP Version 5.2.17 Linux Apache

Comment: use ob_get_contents() instead :)

Comment: try ob_get_contents() then ob_clean();

Comment: @Shehabix No difference was made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correctly executed because this is how ob_get_clean works:

[ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

```
ob_get_clean — Get current buffer contents and delete current output buffer
```

> Returns the contents of the output buffer **and end output buffering**. If
>   output buffering isn't active then FALSE is returned.

Use ob_get_contents();

```
ob_start();
include('test.php');
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo("Included{".$content."}");
```

Update:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<?php 
include('contentbox1.php'); 
include('contentbox2.php'); 
include('contentbox3.php'); 
?>
<b>Bye</b>
<?php
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo("Included{".$content."}");
?>
```

Comment: This made no difference and the above result still occurs. It appears that the data isn't even going into the output buffer but rather being directly outputted.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code EXACTLY and the result was the same. `<h1>Welcome</h1>Included{...boxes...<b>Bye</b>}`

Comment: can you show the code of contentbox1.php? see if there is ob_start()?

Comment: Ok, the WIERDEST thing just happened. The site has been running really slow lately and has been annoying me. I noticed that all the new code I've been uploading lately has been running fast still. I re-uploaded the site even though nothings changed in a year and boom! My site is fast again and the output buffer works... No freakin idea why... I'd like to thank you heaps for your persistence anyway!! Oh well....

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

add this to the beginning of test.php

```
<?php include("empty_file.php"); ?>
```

content of empty_file.php:

```
<?php
echo "";
?>
```